# Issue converting SUMPRODUCT formula to INDEX+MATCH

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet that shows the actual dollars produced and the expected dollars produced for each employee, where each row is one day and each employee has two columns. I would like to count the number of times an employee came within 10% of their production goal without referencing specific columns. Please look at the [example spreadsheet](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NuUb-Nmp2FJ-0zzfXdr5W027DoRlGGjl/view?usp=sharing).

I want for the formulas in cells `Sheet2!E4:E7` to do what the formulas in `Sheet2!E10:E13` do.

I am trying to avoid using direct column references because it causes me to have to go in and update the columns in the formulas every time a new employee is added to the sheet.

I'm no stranger to using `INDEX+MATCH`, or to converting `SUMPRODUCT` formulas to `INDEX+MATCH`. What I can't get past are the formulas in cells `Sheet2!E4:E7`. If you evaluate the formula you can watch the `INDEX+MATCH` section on the left side of the formula work correctly, and then a nearly identical `INDEX+MATCH` section on the right side evaluate to 0 for no apparent reason.

The formula I'm having trouble with is in cell `Sheet2!E4`:

```
COUNTIF(INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$AZ$314,,MATCH($B4,Sheet1!$A$1:$AZ$1,0)),">"&(INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$AZ$314,,MATCH($B4,Sheet1!$A$1:$AZ$1,0)+1)))
```

The section to the left of the `">"` will match with the correct range (`Sheet1!B2:B314`), however the section to the right of the `">"` will evaluate to `0` instead of `Sheet1!C2:C314`.

This is strange to me because the only real difference between the two sections is the `'+1'` on the end of the `MATCH` function, and adding the `'+1'` to the section to the left of the `">"` produces the expected result for the `MATCH` function (`Sheet1!C2:C314`) as seen by evaluating the formula in cell `Sheet2!E5`.

The formula that produces the correct result is in cell `Sheet2!E10`:

```
SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$313)),--(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$313<Sheet1!$C$2:$C$313),--(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$313>=Sheet1!$C$2:$C$313*0.9))
```

I understand that if I exclude the `'$'` before the column references, any future additions/subtractions to the columns on `Sheet1` will adjust the references accordingly. This solution is not ideal, because there are multiple data sheets (one for each year) where the columns are all different (Dan is column `F` for 2019, `G` for 2018, `M` for 2017, etc.), and the tables using these sheets are laid out in a way that would prevent me from easily being able to auto-update the formulas, so a solution that locates the correct column using the employee's name is preferred.

The correct result should be 2 for Allen and 3 for Torres, but I can only seem to get the `INDEX+MATCH` formulas to return 0, 12, 15, 16, or 17 (depending on what tweaks I make to the formula).

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:  **ARRAY FORMULA CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER**

```
=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(INDEX($A$1:$E$30,2,MATCH(G9,$A$1:$E$1,0)):INDEX($A$1:$E$30,30,MATCH(G9,$A$1:$E$1,0))),INDEX($A$1:$E$30,2,MATCH(G9,$A$1:$E$1,0)):INDEX($A$1:$E$30,30,MATCH(G9,$A$1:$E$1,0))<INDEX($A$1:$E$30,2,MATCH(G9,$A$1:$E$1,0)+1):INDEX($A$1:$E$30,30,MATCH(G9,$A$1:$E$1,0)+1)*(INDEX($A$1:$E$30,2,MATCH(G9,$A$1:$E$1,0)):INDEX($A$1:$E$30,30,MATCH(G9,$A$1:$E$1,0))>=INDEX($A$1:$E$30,2,MATCH(G9,$A$1:$E$1,0)+1):INDEX($A$1:$E$30,30,MATCH(G9,$A$1:$E$1,0)+1)*0.9))*1)
```

and adapt the ranges to your needs. It is entered on the same sheet as the data.

Basically this approach uses   **ARRAY FORMULA CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER**

`INDEX($A$1:$E$30,2,MATCH(G9,$A$1:$E$1,0)):INDEX($A$1:$E$30,30,MATCH(G9,$A$1:$E$1,0)))`

to get the needed ranges. `MATCH` looks for the right column. the row number can be set as needed, here its is from `2` to`30` adapted to your provided data. My search term in this case is in `G9` with Allen as content. The result of the formula is `$B$2:$B$30`. A `+1` after `Match` gives the other range `$C$2:$C$30`. Both ranges can then be evaluated with the needed conditions

Pull it down and provide Torres in `G10`. Then the ranges will be adapted to `$D$2:$D$30` and `$E$2:$E$30`.

[image]

Comment: Masterfully done, this answered my question and solved the problem, and you explained the solution well too. Thank you!